# how to avoid exponential ticks in mayavi's mlab.axes?

Tags: python-2.7, mayavi

Is there a parameter to control that?I can not find it.
I use

```
import numpy as np
from enthought.mayavi import mlab
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from enthought.mayavi.modules.axes import Axes

x,y,z =np.loadtxt('mydata',delimiter=',',usecols=(0,1,2),unpack=True)
xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x),200)
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y),200).reshape(200,1) 
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi),method='nearest')  
mlab.surf(xi,yi,zi,warp_scale="auto")
mlab.axes.label_format='%.2f'
mlab.axes(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', zlabel='z',ranges=(1000,1100,1200),nb_labels=5)
mlab.show()
```

and the ticks are like 1.08e+03 and 1.18e+03 in the output figure.I add 
`mlab.axes.label_format='%.2f'`,but nothing changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to specify it at construction using mlab, but you can dig into the tvtk object (edit: actually it is still traited in the mayavi layer) and modify it:

```
>>> ax=mlab.axes()
>>> ax.axes.label_format
'%-#6.3g'
>>> ax.axes.label_format='%.2f'
```

Notice that it is the `.axes.label_format` format of the axis instance you create that you need to modify.  `ax` is an instance of axis.

Your new code is comparable to the following minimal snippet.  Notice how this does not operate on the instance of axis, `ax`.

```
>>> ax=mlab.axes()
>>> mlab.axes.label_format='%.2f'
```

Comment: Could you please make it clear?I tried you way but did not make it.

Comment: What part of the answer is not clear?

What specifically did you do, and what was the result?

Comment: I revised my post.Please take a look at it.

Comment: You are editing the `label_format` attribute of the `mlab.axes` module, before you create any instance of `axes`.  This is not what you want.  Edit the `label_format` attribute of the axis instance you create.  I have updated my answer to isolate the error in the large code snippet you posted.

Comment: Please forgive my retard.Your method works.I forgot the brackets.I have updated my post,how do you know that?

Comment: The way I figured this out was with an interactive Ipython session.  I just looked at the available traits in the axes object, and saw this one.